# Cannot have access to my cookies in developer tools console

Tags: reactjs, node.js, cookies

Hello Everyone **I have tried all answers related to this issue and can't find a solution, i am a newbie to this and this is the only issue i am having with my code right now, thanks for your help in advance**.  Ok, so i am building a project in which user require cookies for login purposes and other functions. i can find my cookies using localhost and it is possible to work with them. After deploying my site on render for testing, cookies are being displayed in the response but not on the application when i include a domain in my cookie config below

```
response.cookie("login_token", token, {
httpOnly: false,
maxAge: 60 * 60 * 24,
secure: true,
domain: "kids-spelling-game.onrender.com",
sameSite: "none",
```

});

this is the result below

[image: Result in response]

[image: No token in the application dev tools]

But when i remove the domain from my cookie config and deploy on render, i can find my cookie in the application dev tools but in my console, it says undefined. this is the config below

```
  response.cookie("login_token", token, {
httpOnly: false,
maxAge: 60 * 60 * 24,
secure: true,
sameSite: "none",
```

});

this is the result below

[image: Cookie is available in application dev tools]

but in console, it says undefined

[image]

Comment: Please don't use all-caps like this - it's broadly taken as equivalent to shouting.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add cors to your project?

First, install [`cors`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors).

```
npm install cors
```

Then add in your file that uses express cors like this.

```
import cors from 'cors' ;

const corsOptions = {
  // set origin to a specific origin.
  origin : 'http://localhost:3000',
  
  // or, set origin to true to reflect the origin of the request
  //origin : true,

  credentials : true,
  optionsSuccessStatus : 200,
} ;

app.use(cors(corsOptions));
```

Comment: Yes, cors is added with the config above